# Is schema.org/Person useful for a personal home page?

Tags: schema.org, privacy

What are the pros and cons of annotating a personal home page with the http://schema.org/Person microformat?

Answer (score 1):

If the homepage contains content about the person, then providing structured data about this person makes sense. And with the vocabulary Schema.org, the appropriate type would be [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person).

- For conveying that the page is authored by that person, you could use:
  [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) [`author`](http://schema.org/author) [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person)
- For a page that is *about* the person (typically a separate "About" page, but sometimes the homepage is used for this), you could use:
  [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) [`about`](http://schema.org/about) [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person)
- In that case it’s probably also the primary entity:
  [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person)
- etc.

(And you should provide this structured data not *only* on the homepage if the person is also relevant to other pages on the site.)

As you tagged your question with [privacy](/questions/tagged/privacy):

In general, using structured data can make your content more visible/prominent/accessible/popular/….

Either you want the world to know about the person (in which case using structured data can make this more effective), or you don’t (in which case you should probably not provide the content publicly in the first place).

Comment: I'm not sure you've listed any non-vague pros (or cons) of adopting schema.org.  What do I actually get in real terms by participating?  Who participates in it, and how do they benefit from it?

Comment: @cnst: I didn’t because you didn’t ask for it ;) (I thought your question is specifically about `Person`, instead of other types, and the homepage, instead of other pages - with a privacy focus). -- Is your "What do I actually get" question about `Person` on homepages, or about using Schema.org in general? Anyway, I think such a question would be too broad (open ended, and consumers come and go, and what they consume changes, too).

Comment: I do not think it is fair to dismiss it as too general.  It is specifically about `Person` -- with a business/restaurant, I can see some potential value being somewhere, but what about `Person`?